# carte server error with german umlaut

Tags: pentaho, kettle, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I am running the community edition from pentaho with Version 7.1 and i am facing a problem which i can't solve.

I have a transformation where i use german umlaut like ä, ö, ü because i read in text or define text which contains this letters. Nevertheless, in spoon, the transformation is running well, but if i transfer the transformation/job to the carte server, which is running on the same PC, i get the following error from the attachment.

[error picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g80YS.png)

if i remove every of this letters, the transformation/job on the carte server is also running great.

Does somebody have an idea how to configure the server or enviroment, because i cant remove the letters in the german language.

Thanks, Armin

Comment: [**Do not post images of code or errors!**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/995714)

Comment: @Rob Thanks, what to do different?

Comment: Post your code and errors as text, not pictures.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look on Pentaho Jira [PDI-1101](http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PDI-1101).

This was supposed to be fixed since 2008. If it reappeared, make a one step transformation with the problem, and reopen the case.

In the meanwhile, try one of the workaround proposed in the Jira case.